How to add some random data at certain places in a file
With my Computer, it runs a Linux kernel and bash, i will make a technical-experiment.
I have a file, file.dat, size = 1.048.576 byte.
I will add at certain places in file.dat some irregular (1...8 byte) random data from /dev/random.
How to do that and how to remove the random data later?
By certain places i think at the Fibonacci Series, i found some scripts to generate this numbers:
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Program to Find Fibonacci Series"
  echo "How many number of terms to be generated ?"
  read n
  x=0
  y=1
  i=2
  echo "Fibonacci Series up to $n terms :"
  echo "$x"
  echo "$y"
  while [ $i -lt $n ]
  do
      i=`expr $i + 1 `
      z=`expr $x + $y `
      echo "$z"
      x=$y
      y=$z
  done

The other one:
# Read the value of n from user
echo -n "Enter the number of terms: "
read n

# Initialize variables
a=0
b=1

# Print the first two terms
echo -n "$a $b "

# Generate the Fibonacci series
for (( i=2; i<$n; i++ ))
do
    c=$((a + b))
    echo -n "$c "
    a=$b
    b=$c
done

echo

The Fibonacci Series says where to add sometimes 1 ... upto 8 bytes to add with random data.
I know this blows up the 1.048.576 byte file.dat , but that is what i am looking for.
Any ideas how to do that?

easiest way to overwrite with some random bytes would likely be something like dd < /dev/urandom bs=1 count=$N seek=$POS of=file.dat conv=notrunc. Similarly you could apply dd to save those bytes beforehand to be able to restore them later

"and how to remove the random data later?" -- Restore the whole file from backup.

i am not looking for an overwriting way, i am looking for a way to put the random data in between, the fubunacci-series says where to do this. and size of random data should be 1...8 byte, but vary.

The fibonacci series is fixed and grows very quickly, so after 31 iterations you are already indexing beyond the end of the .dat file. How will you know how many bytes were inserted at each index if you want to remove them later? Perhaps the first byte inserted could hold this length? Are you looking for a way to obfuscate the data? You might try steganography or simple encryption methods. Or is it just an exercise, in which case we can pursue.

I'm not sure, whether you have the correct model of a file in your head. In filesystems I know, I can not insert a character at a specific point, thereby pushing the following characters forward, though using an editor gives me exactly that visual impression. When saving the file to disk, all characters from that point have to be rewritten - most often, I guess, the whole file will be rewritten from scratch. You can do so in a script, but if I had to do so, I would think about using dd to write bytewise to fixed positions, and cat the parts together. Or with read -n/-N ….

yes, thats what i mean. but how can i do this with dd in a script?

would it be easier to implement with a fixed value and not the fibunacci-series ?

Here's some code to play with, which does what I understood you wanted. It makes extensive use of dd ibs=1 count=99 to read 99 bytes from stdin to stdout. Since the functions often stdout is the file being created, if you add any debug ensure it writes to stderr, e.g. echo here >&2. Please start a new post to discuss each new feature that you would prefer that it did.
#!/bin/bash
# given a number N from 0 up, return fibonacci number N
fib(){
 local a=0 b=1 c i n=${1?}
 for ((i=1;i<n;i++)){ let c=a+b; a=$b; b=$c; }
 echo $((n==0?0:b))
}
docopy(){ # copy count bytes from stdin to stdout
 local count=${1?}
 dd ibs=1 count=$count status=none
}
doinsert(){ # gen random number 0..7, write it and that many chars to stdout
 let len=$RANDOM%7 # 0..7  plus 1 byte for len char
 printf "$len"
 dd if=/dev/random ibs=1 count=$len status=none
}
doremove(){ # ready next byte and skip that many more bytes
 len=$(dd ibs=1 count=1 status=none) # 1 byte should be 0..7
 if ! [[ $len =~ [0-7] ]]
 then   printf "corrupted input at %s, got byte %c\n" $offset "$len" >&2
        exit 1
 fi
 dd of=/dev/null ibs=1 count=$len status=none
}
 
run(){
 dowhat=${1?}
 filesize=$(stat --format=%s -)
 curpos=0 # current position in stdin, or for doremove in stdout 
 for ((n=6; ;n++)) # start from fibonacci F6 to avoid repeated offset of 1
 do offset=$(fib $n)
    [ $offset -gt $filesize ] && break
    docopy $((offset-curpos))
    curpos=$offset
    $dowhat # insert or remove
 done
 cat
}

# create an example data file of wanted length
man bash >input
while cat input;do :;done | dd ibs=1048576 count=1 iflag=fullblock >file.dat

run doinsert <file.dat >file.new
ls -l file.new
run doremove <file.new >file.restored
cmp -l file.dat file.restored

You can do a byte-by-byte diff with this script:
#!/bin/bash
dodiff(){
 declare a=$1 b=$2 tmp=/tmp/bdiff$$ flags=-u
 od -cvw1 "$a" |
 sed 's/^....... //;$d' >$tmp
 od -cvw1 "$b" |
 sed 's/^....... //;$d' |
 diff $flags $tmp -
 rm -fr $tmp
}
dodiff file.dat file.restored
dodiff file.dat file.new

